# How can you expand a DIV horizontally to wrap its widest child?

Tags: css

G'day,

The simplest example of what I'm trying to do can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/YxwQW/

How can I expand the red parent div to wrap around it's child div when it's percentage-based width is smaller than the fixed width of the child?

Thanks!

EDIT: Link was wrong, added correct link now. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `min-width` of the parent to be equivalent to the `width` of the child.  See http://jsfiddle.net/YxwQW/1/ (I also added padding just to make the visual a bit clearer).

Comment: Sorry, but I should've mentioned that I do not know the width of the child beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "display: inline-block; min-width: 90%;" if I correctly understand what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/YxwQW/3/